# Phonegap: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. (OS X)

Tags: android, cordova

I'm just learning how to use phonegap following [this guide.](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

But when I tryed to do `$ phonegap build android` this is what I got:

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
  [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 

/Users/myself/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.
at /Users/myself/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:85:29
at _rejected (/Users/myself/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
at /Users/myself/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
at Promise.when (/Users/myself/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/myself/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
at /Users/myself/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
at flush (/Users/myself/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Any ideas?

**PS:**

I'm noob with phonegap, ruby and npm

Comment: Have you installed the Android SDK, Ant, Java JDK and added them to your PATH variable?

Comment: The problem was that Android SDK wasn't added to the PATH. Thanks @DavidAnderson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is received when the Android SDK is not set up correctly. The Android SDK tools and platform-tools folders, Ant and the Java JDK should be added to the PATH.

Adding the Android SDK to the PATH resolved the issue.

Comment: Users/myself/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^         Please install the android platform-19 (latest version of sdk). This error solve once copy platform 19 in my sdk directiory.